# How do I delete an amount of characters from a file that I determine? (Python)

Tags: python, file, read-write

I am taking input from a txt file and want to take 4 characters and then delete them in the file, then take the next 4 characters and read those.

So far I have this:

```
test_file = open("Test.txt", "r+")

text_in_file = test_file.read()
index = 4
intake_piece = text_in_file[:index]
print(intake_piece)
```

All I have found so far is how to delete exact lines that matches strings but I would like to delete characters to a point using the index number I choose.

edit:

I am essentially looking to read in the file, take the first 4 characters (it's a txt file that just has specific characters in a random order), do a function with those and move onto the next 4, until the end of the file.

I've managed to jury rig a way to achieve a similar result to what I want here:

```
index_start = 0
index_finish = 4
count =1

test_file = open("dna.txt", "r")


read_file = test_file.read()
file_size = read_file.__len__()
print((file_size))
i = 1
index = 0
while(index < file_size):

    print('the count is', count)
    count += 1

    index += 4
    print('index: ',index)
    intake = read_file[index_start:index_finish]
    print(intake)

    index_start += 4
    index_finish +=4

    text_file_output = open("Output%i.txt"%i,'w')
    i += 1
    text_file_output.write(intake)
    text_file_output.close()
    path = os.path.abspath("Output%i")
    directory = os.path.dirname(path)
    print(path)

test_file.close()
```

Comment: Is it always the _first 4_?

Comment: Do you really want to delete them from the file or just ignore them?

Comment: are you doing it recursively throughout the file or are you only concerned about the first 8 characters?

Comment: If your question is what's under the edit, `text_in_file.read(4)` will do. If the function returns `''`, it has reached the end. Though, I see no reason why not to read the whole file in one go and then use a loop to slice the string.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be as good but I am looking to output the 4 characters into a cell in excel. Would using a string splitter make this easier or harder?

Comment: Okay, so, what is your complete question? Is it "I have a text file. I want to read 4 characters at a time and put them in excel cells"? How big is your file? What is the format of the file? Does it have any newlines, tabs, spaces you want to ignore? Show us an example.

Comment: I want to take a txt file that is 9kb in size and format it so that in excel there are 4 characters in each cell. The data itself just consists of TCAG characters without spaces. My latest edit on the post shows somewhat what I am looking to achieve.

Comment: Okay, that's clearer. However, you've already demonstrated a way to take 4 characters at a time, so what are you trying to get answered here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to remove the first 4 letters from the file, you can use regular expressions:

```
import re
characters = re.findall("[\w\W]", open('file.txt').read())
final_data = ''.join(characters[4:])
```

Comment: What've regular expressions got to do with this?

Comment: @JonClements my understand of the problem is that the OP wants to delete the first `n` characters, not lines. With `re.findall` the OP can get an entire listing of all the characters in the file, and then use the list slicing technique to remove the first `n`, or build on the slicing.

Comment: Okay... so I guess it depends whether we're talking characters or bytes then I guess... I was thinking `open('file.txt').read()[4:]`

Comment: You are right in that I would like to delete n characters after utilising them. The reason being that the file I will be using is too large to import and then do what I need to with the data.

Comment: @JRE you do realise that to remove 4 characters from the start of a file you normally need to read/write the remainder of the file to another (which if it's large can be an expensive operation)? Can't you just leave the file there and read it in chunks, and if you need to pick bits from it use `file.seek` to jump bits already processed?

Comment: @JonClements This is my first foray into this kind of programming so I'm unsure on specifics of read/write functionality. Ideally what I am looking to achieve is an output of three tables that use a number of characters I define. With the deletion of the start of the file I imagine it would help to run more smoothly, although I am happy to be wrong of course.